# Autosys Job Queue

Tags: autosys

I'm trying to set<sup>1</sup> an autosys jobs configuration so that will have a "funnel" job queue behavior, or, as I call it, in a 'waterdrops' pattern, each job executing in sequence after a given time interval, with local job failure not cascading into sequence failure.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>(ask for it to be setup, actually, as I do not control the Autosys machine)</sub>

---

## Constraints

- I have an (arbitrary) N jobs (all executing on *success* of job A)

  - For this discussion, lets say three (B1, B2, B3)
  - Real production numbers might go upward of 100 jobs.
  - All these jobs won't be created at the same time, so addition of a new job should be as *less painful* as possible.
- None of those should execute simultaneously.

  - Not actually a *direct* problem for our machine
  - **But** side effect on a remote, client machine : jobs include file transfer, which are trigger-listened to on client machine, which doesn't handle well.

    - Adaptation of client-machine behavior is, unfortunately, *not possible*.
- Failure of job is meaningless to other jobs.
- There should be a regular delay in between each job

  - This is a *soft* requirement in that, our jobs being batch scripts, we can always append or prepend a *sleep* command.
  - I'd rather, however have a more elegant solution especially if the delay is centralised : a parameter - that could be set to greater values, should the need arise.

---

## State of my reasearch

**Legend**

A(s) : **Success** status of job
A(d) : **Done** status of job

### Solution 1 : Unfailing sequence

*This is the current "we should pick this solution" solution.*

> A (s) --(delay D)--> B(d) --(delay D)--> B2(d) --(delay D)--> B3 ...

**Pros :**

- Less bookeeping than solution 2

**Cons :**

- Bookeeping of the (current) tailing job
- Sequence doesn't resist to job being **ON HOLD** (**ON ICE** is fine).

### Solution 2 : Stairway parallelism

> A(s) ==(delay D)==> B1
>   A(s) ==(delay D x2)==> B2
>   A(s) ==(delay D x3)==> B3
>   ...

**Pros :**

- Jobs can be put **ON HOLD** without incidence.

**Cons :**

- Bookeeping to know "who is when" (and what's the next delay to implement)
- N jobs executed at the same time
- Underlying race condition created
  ++ Risk of overlap of job execution, especially if small delays accumulates

### Solution 3 : The Miracle Box ?

I have read a bit about Job Boxes, but the specific details eludes me.

> -----------------
>   A(s) ====> | B1, B2, B3 |
>          -----------------

- Can we limit the number of concurrent executions of jobs of a box (i.e a box-local *max_load*, if I understand that parameter) ?

**Pros :**

- Adding jobs would be painless
- Little to no bookeeping (box name, to add new jobs - and it's constant)
- Jobs can be put **ON HOLD** without incidence (unless I'm mistaken)

**Cons :**

- I'm half-convinced it can't be done (but that's why I'm asking you :) )
- ... any other problem I have failed to forseen

---

## My questions to SO

1. Is Solution 3 a possibility, and if yes, what are the specific commands and parameters for implementing it ?
2. Am I correct in favoring Solution 1 over Solution 2 otherwise<sup>2</sup> ?
3. An alternative solution fitting in the constraints is of course more than welcome!

Thanks in advance,
Best regards

PS: By the way, is all of this a giant [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) manager for the remote machine failing behavior ?
[Yes, it is](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BluntYes).

<sup>2</sup> <sub>I'm aware it skirts a bit toward the "subjective" part of questions rejection rules, but I'm asking it in regards to the solution(s) correctness toward my (arguably) objective constraints.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to do below

1. Put all the jobs (B1,B2,B3) in a box job B.
2. Create another job (say M1) which would run on success of A. This job will call a shell/perl script (say forcejobs.sh)
3. The shell script will get a list of all the jobs in B and start a loop with a sleep interval of delay period. Inside loop it would force start jobs one by one after the delay period.

   So outline of script would be

   ```
     get all the jobs in B
     for each job start for loop
          force start the job
     sleep for delay interval
   ```
4. At the end of the loop, when all jobs are successfully started, you can use an infinite loop and keep checking status of jobs. Once all jobs are SU/FA or whatever, you can end the script and send the result to you/stdout and finish the job M1.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to come back and accept your answer - it was really helpful. (It didn't solve my RL problem in that the powers that be refused it as outside-of-enterprise-standards, but hey, that's life for you...)

Comment: Np bro. Happy to help.